# guzzlehttp conflict issue while upgrading from 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am upgrading my website from version 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.4

I run the following command to add the version 2.4.4 in my composer.json

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update
```

And then running the composer update command gives me the following error

```
composer update


Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.4].
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.4.4 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.5.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires predictionio/predictionio ^0.13.0 -> satisfiable by predictionio/predictionio[v0.13.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.3.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.3.0, ..., 7.5.x-dev].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: guzzlehttp/guzzle[v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v2.0.0, ..., v2.8.8, v3.0.0, ..., v3.8.1, 4.0.0-rc.1, ..., 4.x-dev, 5.0.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev, 7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.5.x-dev].
- Conclusion: install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.4 (conflict analysis result)
```

The conflict arises because predictionio/predictionio package and magento/product-community-edition have different requirements for the guzzlehttp/guzzle package.

Could someone please suggest how I can fix this conflict issue as I could not find anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/apache/predictionio-sdk-php
the package is abandoned and no longer maintained (last commit is 5 year old)

i see a fork already started it

https://github.com/nexumprofessiondev/predictionio-sdk-php/commits/guzzle7

So the option i can see is to fork this repo and upgrade the package to require guzzle 7 and make adjustment from the package you just forked to be compatible with guzzle 7.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. According to you I need to fork the above repo and make changes to predictionio-sdk-php to make it compatible with guzzle 7.

Comment: yes that's it :)